# Problem with implementation of Adapter Pattern

Tags: c++, adapter

I have a question - how to "convert" first interface into another using Adapter Pattern in following example? If second interface uses additional argument, I can't use this argument, if Adapter inherits from first interface (which has only one argument). What should I do?

```
#include <iostream>

class IFirstClass
{
public:
    virtual void perform(std::string name) = 0;
};

class ISecondClass
{
public:
    virtual void furtherPerform(std::string name, std::string desc) = 0;
};

class FirstClass : public IFirstClass
{
public:
    virtual void perform(std::string name)
    {
        std::cout << "Performing action: " << name << "\n";
    }
};

class SecondClass : public ISecondClass
{
public:
    virtual void furtherPerform(std::string name, std::string desc)
    {
        std::cout << "Performing action: " << name << " with description: " << desc << "\n";
    }
};

class Adapter : public IFirstClass
{
private:
    SecondClass& derived;
public:
    Adapter(SecondClass& derived) : derived{ derived }
    {

    }
    virtual void perform(std::string name)
    {
        derived.furtherPerform(name, ? );
    }
};
int main()
{
    FirstClass a;
    SecondClass b;
    Adapter c(b);
    c.perform("Name", "Description");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put an adapter between interface1 and interface2, so that you can use interface2 through the adapter.

You have to make a decision on how are you going to deal with the fact that the method you need to adapt, requires more params than interface2.

a solution might be to use always a known value as a parameter (empty string, valorized string, etc).

another solution might be to pass that string into the adapter constructor

another solution might be to ask a function every time that you need to determine that value.

it really depends on what you need to adapt.